# SSAS - 'group by' equivalent MDX Calculation

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

My Fact table looks like this:

ticketID    price           statusID

1                 100                    1

2                       100                    1

2                       100                    2

3                       150                    1

I am using SSAS to create an OLAP Cube for my data warehouse.
I cannot use the aggregateFunction 'Sum' for the measure 'total price', because I will get 450$ instead of 350$ (which is the correct tatal)

Regards

Comment: Do you want to group by ticketID?

Comment: hey! yes this is what I want

Comment: Is there one price per ticket?

Comment: Yes, indeed....

Comment: why don't you just filter by statusID 1?

Comment: A ticket might skip StatusID 1 and jump directly to 2 or 3 ... it is not sequential.

Comment: Do you want to get the ticket with the maximum status value if that ticket has multiple status?

Comment: if yes, then create a view as the source of cube dsv like this: select  ticketid,price,statusid from(select ticketid,price,statusid, row_number()over(partition by ticketid, price order by statusid desc) as rn from yourFactTb ) as fact where rn=1

Comment: That will work since all the rows of the same ticket have got the same price, so any row/value of the same ticket should work. That meens each ticket should be counted once.

Comment: thanks Tom, but I need all the rows from the fact table for other meesures. So I need to bring all the data and then filter with an MDX query...

Answer (score 1):

Then you can still add a view in db like this:

```
select 
    ticketid,
    price,
    statusid,
    case when rn=1 then 1 else 0 end as IsMaxStatus 
from
(select ticketid,price,statusid, 
     row_number()over
     (partition by ticketid, price order by statusid desc) as rn 
     from yourFactTb 
) as fact
```

Then add a dimension [IsMaxStatus] which inlcuded two records of 0/1 in your cube and set the Dim-usage as regular with that measure-group depended on above fact table, and then add a calculated measure say [cal-price] with below formula:

```
with member [cal-price] as
([Price],[IsMaxStatus].[IsMaxStatus].&[1])

select [cal-price] on 0
from [YourCube]
```

You can also calculate other measure by this measure-group without the filter of dim [IsMaxStatus]

Hope it helps.

www.mdx-helper.com